# Python: Read fields of CSV File with a list of list

Tags: python, list, csv

i just wondering how i can read special field from a CVS File with next structure:

```
40.0070222,116.2968604,2008-10-28,[["route"], ["sublocality","political"]]
39.9759505,116.3272935,2008-10-29,[["route"], ["establishment"], ["sublocality", "political"]]
```

the way that on reading cvs files i used to work with:

```
with open('routes/stayedStoppoints', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
```

The problem with that is the first 3 fields no problem i can use:

```
for row in spamreader:
```

row[0],row[1],row[2] i can access without problem. but in the last field and i guess that with csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"') split also for each sub-list:

so when i tried to access just show me:

```
[["route"]
```

Anyone has a solution to handle the last field has a full list ( list of list indeed)

```
[["route"], ["sublocality","political"]]
```

in order to can access to each category.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your format is close to json. You only need to wrap each line in brackets, and to quote the dates.
For each line `l` just do:

```
lst=json.loads(re.sub('([0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+)',r'"\1"','[%s]'%(l)))
```

results in `lst` being

```
[40.0070222, 116.2968604, u'2008-10-28', [[u'route'], [u'sublocality', u'political']]]
```

You need to import the json parser and regular expressions

```
import json
import re
```

***edit***: you asked how to access the element containing 'route'. the answer is

```
lst[3][0][0]
```

'political' is at

```
lst[3][1][1]
```

If the strings ('political' and others) may contain strings looking like dates, you should go with the solution by @unutbu

Comment: Yes! actually my last field is a request to google places, but how could access to first list in categories? i mean how i can read route to compare with others?

Answer (score 2):

Use `line.split(',', 3)` to [split on just the first 3 commas](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
import json
with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
    for line in csvfile:
        row = line.split(',', 3)
        row[3] = json.loads(row[3])
        print(row)
```

yields

```
['40.0070222', '116.2968604', '2008-10-28', [[u'route'], [u'sublocality', u'political']]]
['39.9759505', '116.3272935', '2008-10-29', [[u'route'], [u'establishment'], [u'sublocality', u'political']]]
```

Answer (score 2):

That is not a valid CSV file. The `csv` module won't be able to read this.

If the line structure is always like this (two numbers, a date, and a nested list), you can do this:

```
import ast
result = []
with open('routes/stayedStoppoints') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        coord_x, coord_y, datestr, objstr = line.split(",", 3)
        result.append([float(coord_x), float(coord_y),
                      datestr, ast.literal_eval(objstr)])
```

Result:

```
>>> result
[[40.0070222, 116.2968604, '2008-10-28', [['route'], ['sublocality', 'political']]],
 [39.9759505, 116.3272935, '2008-10-29', [['route'], ['establishment'], ['sublocality', 'political']]]]
```

Comment: ok but the problem is how i can read or extract each category or group of categories for each line!

Comment: @taonico: What do you mean? They already have been extracted into a nested list. For example, using `result` from above, `result[0][3][0][0]` is `"route"`, `result[0][3][1][1]` is `"political"`, `result[1][3][1][0]` is `"establishment"` etc.